# Mock object setup method with arguments to return dynamically

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a class Position and I want to test method CreatePosition. Method looks like this:

```
public Position CreatePosition(int horizontalIndex, int verticalIndex)
{
    return new Position(horizontalIndex, verticalIndex);
}
```

Interface IPosition:

```
public interface IPosition
{
     char HorizontalPosition { get; }
     int VerticalPosition { get; }
     int IndexHorizontal { get; }
     int IndexVertical { get; }
     Position CreatePosition(int horizontalIndex, int verticalIndex);
}
```

Method CreatePosition is used here and it's dynamic - for each pair of parameters it creates new Position:

```
    private void AddToAllowedPositions(IPosition positionCreator)
    {
          int horizontalIndex = piece.Position.IndexHorizontal;
          int verticalIndex = piece.Position.IndexVertical;

          while(IndexesAreValid(horizontalIndex, verticalIndex)
         {
                IPosition currentPosition = positionCreator.CreatePosition(horizontalIndex, verticalIndex);
                allowedPosition.Add(currentPosition);
         }
    }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to fake method CreatePosition.

I've created `Mock<IPosition>` like this:

```
Mock<IPosition> positionCreator = new Mock<IPosition>();
positionCreator.Setup(positionCreator.Object.CreatePosition(?, ?)).Returns( ?? );
```

I would like to fake that method so it will accept dynamic parameters and return dynamic results, just like real Position is doing. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this in your test method:

```
positionCreator
    .Setup(x => x.CreatePosition(It.IsAny<int>, It.IsAny<int>))
    .Returns(new Position(givenHorizontalIndex, givenVerticalIndex));
```

and you can have various test cases with different inputs and expected outputs.

Or do you want something more elaborate, where you would wire it all up in the `[SetUp]` method, like given that input, return that output?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there a way that I return Mock object instead of new Position? Something like Mock<IPosition>?

Comment: no, the Returns method describes what the actual method (`CreatePosition`) will return when called during the test, so it has to receive a parameter of the same type as the method's return type

Comment: There is also a problem, because It.IsAny<int> is generic method which returns int, it's not an integer.

Comment: that's just a way of saying that given the method is called with any `int` parameter, it will return what you set it up to return; the alternative would be something like  `.Setup(x => x.CreatePosition(2, 3)`, which means that only if the method will be called with those specific parameters during the test it will return the setup (otherwise it will return null - if you don't do another setup, that is)

Comment: What about giveHorizontalIndex, givenVerticalIndex? They are not defined, but they are supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: have a look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: You've gave a wonderful idea - mock each object separately with indexes inserted. After all I expect only 14 results which is not that much of typing.